# modular calculation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$21 \equiv 4\pmod{17} \equiv \ ?$$

What does this expression mean? I know what mod mean, and what $\equiv$ means, but together this equation doesn't seems meaning anything.  The $21\equiv 4 \mod{17}$ makes sense, but what's the succeeding part ?

Comment: What context did you see that in?

Comment: it's just a quiz with this one sentence, and the answer is 38

Comment: There are many integers which are $4\pmod {17}$.  $21$ and $38$ are certainly examples, but there are infinitely many examples.  Without more information there's no way to say why $38$ was the official solution and not, say, $55$.

Comment: You have the solution set $\{...-27, -13, 4, 21, 38, ...\}$.

Comment: Sometime people who write quizzes make mistakes.  It's not clear what they are asking and putting the $\mod 17$ in the middle is confusing but not technically wrong.  I would have to assume (but wouldn't be able to say it is obvious) that they want us to name another integer that is congruent to $4$ or $21\pmod{17}$.  I'd personally answer $-13$ because... well, why not? As lulu points out there are infinitely many answers.  I think this question was written by someone who knew enough to know what $\mod 17$ means didn't know enough to know there are infinite answers.  Life is irritating.

Comment: The question was very poorly posed to you.  It should read: $21 \equiv 4\pmod{17}$.  Find the next least greater integer $n$ such that $n\equiv 4 \pmod{17}$.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense.

Comment: Glad to help, @YoYo

Comment: " Find the next least greater integer n such that n≡4(mod17)."  If that *is* what the question was going for.  Because the question *was* so very badly written I don't think we can ever know what they *did* have in mind.  Anyhow, I think the OP understands the subject well enough she should not worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$21\equiv4\bmod17$ means $17|21-4$.  In fact, $21\equiv4+17k\bmod17$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$.

In particular, taking $k=2$, we have $21\equiv38\bmod17$.

So $38$ is *an* answer, but there are infinitely many acceptable others, including $55$ for example.